What does 二人ならおっぱいも二倍の四つだしね mean?
I am confused about this sentence, especially 二倍の四つ

二人ならおっぱいも二倍の四つだしね

I am familiar with 倍 in sentences like あの山は東京タワーの3倍の高さだ but not in this sentence. Since each woman has two breasts, I think 二倍の四つ is supposed to be 二つの乳房の二倍の四つ (4 which is 2 times 2 breasts)?
Also, can おっぱい refer to a single breast, not two?

FYI, I've fixed the typo where the title and the text of the question had a lot of katakana ニ instead of kanji 二. Perhaps you should check your conversion history.

The 二倍の四つ here should be interpreted as

四つ, which is 二倍

Just like how 僕は学生の千雨です, or こちらが作家の渡辺さん would mean 千雨, which is 学生 or 渡辺さん, which is 作家, the AのB structure used A to define B, instead of signifying possession.
Similar constructs exist in English as well. Take for example:

I really like Turkey.
What Turkey? The animal of Turkey? (Turkey, which is animal)
No, the country of Turkey (Turkey, which is country)


僕はタイが大好き
何のタイ？魚の鯛{たい}？ (TAI, which is fish)
いや、国のタイ (TAI, which is country)

In Japanese, AのB can both mean A's B(possession) and "B, which is A"(definition). Just like how in English "the B of A" can mean both A's B(possession) and also "B, which is A"(definition). The same logic applies to the 2倍の四つ in question. (2倍になったら四つになる)
As for the usage of おっぱい, since Japanese, unlike English, does not have plural forms of nouns, whether it refers to a single or a pair of breasts would depend on the context.

Thank you the answer but I am not asking about の in the first place. I am specifically asking about the meaning of 二倍. Like how can it mean 4, not 2.

@weeab00 Like you said, everyone knows each woman has two breasts, so saying "2倍の4つ" ("double (boobs), which is four (boobs)") makes perfect sense to me.
